# JavaFX приложение не запускается

Tags: java, javafx

Проблема состоит в следующем, мой jar файл запускается в товарища на ноуте, а у меня нет. Версия jdk у нас одинаковая. При запуске через `cmd` получаю

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
```

В чем может быть проблема? Если создавать не JavaFX проект а просто Java тогда все ок.

Comment: Какой командой вы запускаете jar файл? Версия JDK не влияет на запуск JAR файлов, за их запуск отвечает JVM.

Comment: Запускаю jar через двойной клик, в `cmd` java -jar a.jar

Comment: Попробуйте запустить вот так: "java -cp a.jar Main", вам стоит почитать про ClassPath и запуск приложения, не имеющего пакеты. Для запуска такого приложения нужно создать файл manifest.txt с тремя строками: "Manifest-Version: 1.0", 
"Class-Path: .", 
"Main-Class: Main"

Comment: Ничего не изменилось

Comment: А путь к файлу? Знаю бывает такое, когда появляется какое-то "Андрей" кирилицей в пути к файлу